# Regex - Only detect if all single digits in all four octets

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am trying to capture IP addresses or version numbers via regex. Here are are my three conditions -

**Condition1 :-** Match if only single digits in all the four octets.
E.g. - `oids.serialNumber = '2.5.4.5';`

**Condition2 :-** Don't match if more than 3 dots.
E.g. - `"System.Data.Entity": "4.0.0.1.0";` (4 dots here.)

**Condition3 :-** IP/Version number may or may not be in the middle of the string.
E.g. - `"System.Data.Entity": "4.0.0.1.0";` (middle of the string)
E.g. - `1.0.0.0` - (start of the string)

I have created this regex - `([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])` to capture the above but while running the test cases, i am not getting proper results.

Here are my test cases -

```
1.0.0.0 - Detect
"System.DirectoryServices": "11.0.0.0" - Don't Detect
"System.Web.Services": "244.0.0.0", - Don't Detect
"System.Security": "4.01.0.0",  - Don't Detect
"System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.011.0.0",  - Don't Detect
"System.Data.Entity": "4.0.01.0", - Don't Detect
oids.street = '2.5.244.9'; - Don't Detect
oids.serialNumber = '2.5.4.5'; - Detect
oids.serialNumber = '2.5.4.11'; - Don't Detect
oids.serialNumber = '2.5.4.111';  - Don't Detect
```

Comment: Or `\A[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\z` (most, not JS and Python), or `\A[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\Z` (Python `re`).

Comment: I tried this but its not passing all the test cases, especially third from the last.

Comment: Use `(?<![0-9])(?<![0-9]\.)[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9](?!\.?[0-9])`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/B9KM8f/1/).